# How to randomly generate turtles in netlogo that do not overlap/touch

Tags: loops, netlogo

I am building a parking model and am having trouble when I set up my model. Users are allowed to select the number of parked cars and I currently have the program randomly generating these turtles on rounded random x-coordinates (ensuring all turtles are on only one space/patch). The problem is multiple turtles can be located on the same patch. Is there a way to create these turtles so that they do not lay on the same patch, while randomizing the x-coordinate? If not, I was envisioning a do-until type of loop to keep moving turtles forward until the patch the turtle was on had no other turtles on it.

If the loop is the clear solution, I have never used a loop in this program, and would really benefit from seeing an example, but if that is too much to ask I'm sure I could find one posted online somewhere.

```
    to setup-turtles 
  ask n-of 10 patches with [pycor = -1] [
    sprout 1
  ]
  print max [count turtles-here] of patches

  ask turtles with [who > 0]
    [set color blue
    set shape "car"
    set heading 90
    set xcor round random-xcor
    set ycor -1  ;; this ycor indicates that it is in the parking lane
    set pcolor red
    ]
```

Comment: Uh… what's your question?

Comment: So sorry! Is ther a way to generate the turtles with random rounded x-coordinates while at the same time ensuring that the turtles do not overlap on their respective patches. I need for only one turtle to be on a patch at a time when i set the model up.

Comment: I think looping is the only way. A google search brings up [this](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/loop.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution approach would be to use `n-of`, so e.g. to make 20 turtles,

```
ask n-of 20 patches with [pycor = 0] [
  sprout 1
]
```

So for example if we test it with:

```
to test
  clear-all
  ask n-of 20 patches with [pycor = 0] [
    sprout 1
  ]
  print max [count turtles-here] of patches
end
```

the result printed is always `1`.

Comment: This still results in multiple turtles on the same patch.

Comment: Does it? I have edited the answer to state my assumptions and to include test code. Are you using different assumptions?

Comment: The resulted print is 1 for me as well, however when I right click on a turtle, I am given 2 options to pick which turtle I want to inspect. (Turtle 6 and turtle 8 are both present on patch -5 -1. I am unsure why the count isn

Comment: Cannot reproduce — with the above code, I only ever see get one turtle on the menu when I right-click.

Comment: My resulted print is 1 as well, but when I right click on a turtle, I am given 2 turtles to choose to observe. 
I will try to post a picture above. I am not sure why it will not pick up the extra turtles on the count.

Comment: I can try to post the code that creates the turtles.

Comment: I cannot post the picture because I don't have enough reputation points, but the count being generated says 1, but I have both turtles 1 and 2 on the same patch. I found this after multiple iterations of the code. I really appreciate all of your help with this matter.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I would believe what `max [count turtles-here] of patches` says over what the UI says, if the two are in conflict. I cannot account for why they might be in conflict; we haven't received any bug reports along those lines. I suspect you and I are running different code or following different steps.

Comment: My error was setting the xcor to be random later in my code. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use the turtles-here primitive.  Check out the following which will only add turtles to patches on pycor 1 if there's no other turtles on the patch:

```
let new-patch one-of patches with [ (pycor = 1) and not any? turtles-here ]

if new-patch != nobody [
  ask new-patch [ sprout 1 ]
]
```

See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here

Comment: Thank you! Is this sprouting a new patch? Or sprouting a new turtle on the empty patch?
 I do not intend on covering all patches just a random number of them, which I could alter this to include an if statement to achieve this goal. But to be sure, this code places a turtle on every empty patch?